# Here Map api Multi-reverse Geocode is giving 503 service unavailable

Tags: rest, here-api

I am working with Here map multi-reversergeocode api.

I have generated my own app_id and app_code and trying to hit the api from my java code. But I'm getting `503 Service unavailable` error.

```
WebTarget target = client.target("https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/multi-reversegeocode.xml?mode=retrieveAddresses&gen=9&app_id=<APP_ID>&app_code=<APP_CODE>");
Response response = target.request().post(Entity.text(payload));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following instructions provided in example https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/multi-reverse-geocode and was able to successfully get the response. Also it works fine for https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/multi-reversegeocode.xml post url. Please check if you are body and headers are set properly. If you still face issue share your input/body.

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: *' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -d 'id=0001&prox=52.5309,13.3845,50
id=0002&prox=50.1618,8.5334,50
id=0003&prox=40.7296,-73.9868,50
id=0004&prox=47.6098,-122.3425,50
id=0005&prox=-22.9804,-43.1897,50
id=0006&prox=-8.4943,115.2533,50
id=0007&prox=28.6338,77.2191,50
id=0008&prox=-33.9204,18.4208,50
id=0009&prox=21.0027,-89.6224,50
id=0010&prox=24.6607,46.712,50' \
  'https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/multi-reversegeocode.json?mode=retrieveAddresses&gen=9&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ'
```